# Synchronicity / FIWARE: Error in IDM communication

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-wilma, fiware-keyrock

we are deploying Synchronicity (https://gitlab.com/synchronicity-iot/platform-deployment-docker/-/tree/master/manual) using docker-compose with all the defaults that comes with the config files. Now we are facing a communication error between IdM Keyrock and the PEP Proxy Wilma Plus (service called pep-cb in the file compose-sec-pep.yml). We have registered a new App in Keyrock, in order to securize Orion Context Broker, and with the Client ID and the Client Secret (encoding with base64) we get a value to use in the Authorization HEADER:

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:3000/oauth2/token' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic wMDAteHByZXNzd2ViYXBwOnR1dG9yaWFsLWRja3Itc2l0ZS0wMDAwLWNsaWVudHNlY3JldA==' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data "username=alice-the-admin@test.com&password=test&grant_type=password"
```

This App we have registered is only with the purpose of obtaining a Client ID and a Secret ID in order to get this Authorization to bypass from Wilma (running on port 7000) to Orion Context Broker (running on port 1026). So, now we have a TOKEN (let us named it: X-Access-token) and if we try to do:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://localhost:1027/v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001?options=keyValues \
  -H 'X-Auth-Token: {{X-Access-token}}'
```

we always get the response: Error in IDM communication. We are stuck in this error. Could you please help us or tell us what are we doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Greetings,